# Inno Setup: Specify Date in local format

Tags: delphi, excel, locale, inno-setup, pascal

My application uses Inno Setup to create some registry settings which are later read by an Excel addin. One of these settings is a date.

What I am looking for is a function (in Inno-Setup-friendly Pascal) that takes a date (formatted as a string) and outputs it using the local system date format on whatever computer it runs on. Something like

```
function GetLocalVersionOfShortDate(dateString : String): String;
begin
 // take dateString and convert/display it as local date
end;
```

The output should be in short date format with the local date separator.

For example, I would pass "January 20, 1980" to this function and it would return "01/20/1980" (in America) and "20/01/1980" (in France).

Any thoughts on how to do that? I feel like it's something simple but I'm not familiar enough with Pascal to write the code myself.

Thank you!

Comment: Inno doesn't natively support any date functions bar "get current date/time". Isn't it better all around to store dates as a single value (fixed format string or days since XX) though?

Comment: I'm not sure. A fixed format string ("01/20/1980") would be a different date depending on the locale.

Comment: No, a fixed format string will be locale independant and unambigious, e.g. `yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be a way of doing this by calling into Windows libraries.

Check the section in the INNO help file called "Pascal Scripting: Using DLLs".

http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/

### ALTERNATIVE 1

You could do this by running an executable from either the Run section or via a function using the Exec method. If you are just writing registry settings then this should suffice. Then after the executable has run you could remove it by defining your own ssPostInstall method.

Comment: Ugh, not sure that's what I was looking for. Seems complicated for a simple thing like local date formatting.

Comment: Ugly, yes I know. But INNO does not have anything that works with date s other than the function GetDateTimeString.

Comment: I have amended my answer with another possibility. I hope this is better for you.

Comment: Thank you. I'm still not sure how to handle this but your answer provided some options.